# Spring Boot & Angular 2: Downloading File

Tags: spring, angular

I have app with Spring Boot in backend and Angular 2 in the frontend.

My Controller on backend returns **FileSystemResource**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource getFile() {
    ...
    return new FileSystemResource(fileName);
}
```

and I wonder how can I catch that file in the frontend and let it by downloaded.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can just add the download tag to your html like `<a href="/geFile" download="filename.file"/>` anchor link having `geFile` uri. `FileSystemResource` constructor accepts the file argument and sets the file and path variables.

Comment: I tried your advice, but I got "Failed - No file" and the controller function is not called. I guess I am missing some config in defining getFile()  function.

Comment: Is it `getFile` or `geFile`? Try with the appropriate one.

Comment: Sorry, there was it a typo, but in my code it is correct.

Comment: Okay, you don't need a config to trigger `getFile()` method in Controller class. Just invoking `/getFile` url should be fine. Can you remove the download tag in `<a>` and try to print the filename inside `getFile()` method like `System.out.println(fileName);`

Comment: Finally, I am able to download requested file, however it keeps downloading as json but it is actually pdf. In Controller function I have response.setContentType("application/pdf"); and in <a tag I have download="test.pdf"

Comment: What is the controller annotation? RestController or Controller? Also, remove @ResponseBody annotation and try

Comment: Ok, I solve that by adding produces in @RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces="application/pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: Glad to know you solved it  please post it as an answer